# conditional rendering of class name in angular

Tags: angular, rendering, classname

I'm new to angular and I had this problem last 2 day on how to concatenate dynamic class name in angular 2. Like this code in react.js `className=this-is-a-str${isFoo? 'add this' : 'then this'}` something like that in angular. heres my code in anguar.

```
[className]="getDesignStatus(design).hasError ? 'project--btn btn btn-action btn-danger-invert col-md-3 col-lg-3' : 'project--btn  btn btn-action btn-primary-invert col-md-3 col-lg-3'"
```

the string that only changing is these 2 `btn-danger-invert` &&  `btn-primary-invert`

Answer (score 2):

Just rename `className` to `ngClass` and add static classes using regular html class attribute

```
<div 
  class="project--btn btn btn-action col-md-3 col-lg-3" 
  [ngClass]="getDesignStatus(design).hasError ? 'btn-danger-invert' : 'btn-primary-invert'"
></div>
```

Comment: holy crap dude. you saved a life! thank you so much!

Comment: No worries, mate :)